# React/Redux Form - get ID of input onFocus and set state

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a form with a single textarea. When text is entered into this textarea a new textarea should be displayed under the current one. If this new textarea has text entered then again another new one shows underneath (and on and on...).

In order to prevent a new textarea being added every time text is entered (for example if there are 3 textareas and the user focuses and changes the text in the first) I am storing the activeBulletPointId in my state, and when text is entered in it I am checking to see if it is the last bullet point in the array.

```
addNewBulletToEnd = () => {
    let lastBulletId = this.state.data.slice(-1);
    lastBulletId = lastBulletId[0].id;
    if (this.state.activeBulletPointId === lastBulletId) {
      const newBulletPoint = { id: this.generateId(), title: 'Click to add' };
      this.setState({ data: this.state.data.concat(newBulletPoint) });
    }
  }
```

The issue I have is that when rendering my list I am unsure how to pass the id to the onFocus function.

```
handleFocus = (e) => {
    console.log(e); //Can I get the ID here?
    if (this.state.activeBulletPointId !== selectedBulletPointId) {
      this.setState({ activeBulletPointId: selectedBulletPointId });
    }
  }

render() {
    const bulletList = this.state.data.map((bulletPoint) => {
      const reduxFormName = `${this.props.placeholder}-${bulletPoint.id}`;
      return (
        <div key={bulletPoint.id} className="bullet-point-input">
          <SelectInputType
            placeholder={reduxFormName}
            type="textarea"
            onChange={this.updateText}
            onFocus={this.handleFocus}
            handleKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress(reduxFormName)}
            handleKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
            noLabel
          />
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="bullet-point-list">
        {bulletList}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The `<SelectInputType>` component is what renders my redux-form `<Field>` component.

Comment: have you looked at `FieldArray`? it's exactly what it's for http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.7/examples/fieldArrays/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a handler for each field. So you would avoid keeping data in DOM (as attributes) and keep it in handler's scope.

Unless you have hundreds of fields this wont hit overall performance.

```
setActiveBullet = activeBulletPointId => {
    if (this.state.activeBulletPointId !== activeBulletPointId ) {
      this.setState({ activeBulletPointId });
    }
  }

render() {
    const bulletList = this.state.data.map((bulletPoint) => {
      const reduxFormName = `${this.props.placeholder}-${bulletPoint.id}`;
      return (
        <div key={bulletPoint.id} className="bullet-point-input">
          <SelectInputType
            placeholder={reduxFormName}
            type="textarea"
            onChange={this.updateText}
            onFocus={() => this.setActiveBullet(bulletPoint.id)}
            handleKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress(reduxFormName)}
            handleKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
            noLabel
          />
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="bullet-point-list">
        {bulletList}
      </div>
    );
  }
```